Accidentally set wrong IP address on device
My default gateway IP address is set to 192.168.50.1.
However, I accidentally manually set a device's IP address to 192.168.0.* and now I can't access the device from my WiFi network.
How can I get access to it to change the IP address again?

Update: It's a smart light switch, that has been removed from the cloud. It is using ESPHome so only way to access the settings is via the IP address. I could try reflashing it, but it is already installed and I'm trying to avoid removing it from the wall to re-flash it if at all possible

There should be a reset control on the light switch itself that should set it back to default or "first run" state. That may be the only way to fix this.

if all else fails, setting up a 'dummy' AP with a device running in hotspot mode with the 'right' range might potentially work.

@music2myear You are right, I believe it has a reset button on the back. It is embedded inside the gang box, so I still would have to remove all the switches (it's a 4-gang) which were a PIA to get in there but, that may be the only way if I can't access the the device wirelessly, before attempting to re-flash. Thank you for your suggestion.

@JourneymanGeek will I be able to set up the range to be 192.168.0.* if the default gateway address is 192.168.50.1?

You set up another AP with that range 'seperately' temporarily turn off the main wifi, and use it to resetup the device?

@JourneymanGeek the problem is in the device itself. When I typed in the address manually, I set up the Default Gateway as 192.168.50.1, the Subnet as 255.255.255.0 and the IP address as 192.168.0.*.
manual_ip:       static_ip: 192.168.50.*       gateway: 192.168.50.1       subnet: 255.255.255.0

if it is actually on the wifi network successfully, you can try manually changing your PC adapter address to something in 192.168.0.* and then attempt to connect. You will lose access to the rest of the LAN but you can easily switch the PC back to auto-DHCP.

You need to do the same process in reverse.

Change your gateway to provide DHCP on the same subnet as the switch was set to:
192.168.0.1/24


Connect to the smart light switch using another device and change its IP address from manual back to DHCP to avoid this issue in the future, or a manual address on the correct subnet:
192.168.50.1/24  


Change your gateway back to the original subnet
192.168.50.1/24



Note that it makes more sense to reserve a static IP address for the device in your gateway to have a consistent address than to manually set it in your device.

this worked perfect. I was skeptical about changing the the gateway address since I had set up the gateway manually on the device to 192.168.50.1.  But nonetheless it worked perfectly. I was able to change the ip address back to the correct one. Thank you!
